# Download artifact from Jenkins using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, webclient

I try download artifact from Jenkins using PowerShell, like this:

```
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential ("username", "password")
$url = "http://jenkins/job/jobName/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip" 
$localfilename = "C:\Test\archive.zip"  
$webClient.DownloadFile($url, $localfilename)
```

I get exception:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote
>   server retur ned an error: (403) Forbidden." At C:\ps2.ps1:20 char:28
>   +     $webclient.DownloadFile <<<< ($url, $localfilename)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

If I try download artifact using wget it works:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=username --http-password=password http://jenkins/job/jobName/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip
```

If I using wget without parameter `--auth-no-challenge` I get the same error - `Forbidden`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this authorization in request header is working great:

```
# Create web client with authorization header
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$credentialAsBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($userName + ":" + $password)
$credentialAsBase64String = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($credentialAsBytes);
$webClient.Headers[[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Authorization] = "Basic " + $credentialAsBase64String;
```

Comment: I tried this out on my system and to get it to work I had to change [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII to [System.Text.Encoding]::Default. Not sure what difference that made but I would just like to help the next guy to find this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have basic auth set up on your Jenkins box? If so try this

```
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential ("username", "password")
$url = "http://jenkins/job/jobName/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip" 
$localfilename = "C:\Test\archive.zip"  
$cache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$cache.Add($url, "Basic", $creds)
$webclient.Credentials = $cache
$webClient.DownloadFile($url, $localfilename)
```

Comment: Using the Credentials property seems more elegant than the accepted answer, but I get a 403 Forbidden from jenkins this way. I think the web client will first try without credentials and expects to get a 401 Unauthorized, after which it will retry with credentials. But Jenkins just immediately returns a 403.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this on Jenkins yet, but this is what I am using to download a file attached to an issue in Jira (https):

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://jira.xyz.com/login.jsp?os_username=$username&os_password=$jiraPassword&os_cookie=true" -UserAgent ([Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::InternetExplorer) -SessionVariable myWebSession

Invoke-WebRequest -uri $fileUrlPath -LocalOutFilePath $file -method get -UserAgent ([Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::InternetExplorer) -WebSession $myWebSession
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Jenkins 2.0, [CSRF is enabled by default](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/#cross-site-request-forgery) which requires a session cookie to be provided. In this case you need additional step:

```
$crumbParams = @{
    Headers = @{'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$($credentials.UserName):$($credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password)"))}
    Uri = "$baseUri/crumbIssuer/api/json"
    SessionVariable = 'crumbSession'
}
[void] (Invoke-RestMethod @crumbParams)
```

Note that if you provide your credentials with domain, you might have to use `$credentials.GetNetworkCredential().UserName` if Jenkins expects only username without the domain. The `$baseUri` is the Jenkins address including `http(s)://`.

The previous command will save the session state in `$crumbSession`, from which you can extract the required cookie header:

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $crumbSession.Cookies.GetCookieHeader($baseUri))
$webClient.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Authorization, 'Basic ' + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$($credentials.UserName):$($credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password)")))
$webClient.DownloadFile($url, $localfilename)
```